# Websphere QM configuration - error with musr_mqadmin account

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I was trying to configure my WMQ. 
queue manager was running until i changed the password of my musr_mqadmin account. 
Now it the local queue manager that i created cannot be start any more

The pop up says "The MQ service for installation "installation1" must be running"

While i tried to reset the musr_mqadmin account, it says "mq configuration an error while validating the security credentials "

I am really stuck and helpless. Please kindly advise.

Answer (score 3):

MQ Service runs under MUSR_MQADMIN account. You will need to provide the same password for MQ Service also. Go to `Administrative Tools/Services` console. Select `IBM WebSphere MQ` service and open the properties by double clicking on the service. On the `Log On` tab provide the new password and `OK` to close the dialog and start the service.

HTH/Shashi

Comment: Hi, while trying to reset it. i might have accidently deleted the musr_mqadmin account. is there anyway i can get it back?

Comment: Although I have not tried this: you can try recreating MUSR_MQADMIN user again and add the user to mqm group.

Comment: Windows uses unique SID values. Simply recreating MUSR_MQADMIN won't change the SID that owns the installation and operational files.  Best thing at this point is to uninstall MQ and start over.